# WSET Level 2 Exam

Tags: wine, recommendations, spirits

I'm studying for the WSET Level 2 and I will be taking it in a couple of weeks. Any advice on what I should study? I've already made tons of flash cards and I'm going through them regularly.

Comment: Might have better luck on the [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) if you don't get any replies on here :)

Comment: Level 2 shouldn't be that difficult, check out this website for some tips and mock exams. You'll need to give your email but I've never had any harassing emails from them. https://www.thirtyfifty.co.uk/

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which WSET Level 2 you are taking :)

If you're doing the spirits one, then there are a few things to be certain on:

- Names of things: regions, categories, processes, parts of equipment.
- The choices you can make at each point of production: they like 'which of the following are post-production choices' type of questions.
- Numbers: ABVs, numbers of times things can be done, minimums and maximums.

In general, and this goes for the wine one as well from what I've heard (I've not done it), read the text book, and you'll be fine.